# How to display image which comes from API response in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, api

I'm trying to display the image which i get from api response.

here my api response look like

```
{
            "id": 40,
            "user_id": 49,
            "contact_person": "fss",
            "relation": "dfs",
            "phone": "dsf",
            "image": "emergency/1735859198927595.jpg",
            "created_at": "2022-06-17T05:38:54.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-06-17T05:38:54.000000Z"
        },
```

and displaying it on `listtile` `leading` like this

```
ListTile(leading: SizedBox(height: 50,width: 50,
         child: Image.network(emergencyContact[index].image))
```

but it gives me this error

```
Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file:///emergency/1735859198927595.jpg
```

please help how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the Exception Error explains very well that you did not provide your host: `https://your.site.com/image-path.png`

Please append `https://your.site.com/${emergencyContact[index].image}`

```
ListTile(leading: SizedBox(height: 50,width: 50,
         child: Image.network(`https://your.site.com/${emergencyContact[index].image}`))
```

Answer (score 1):

your image url is not network url, it should start with `https` or `http` other wise it will not work

```
String url = https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png;

ListTile(leading: SizedBox(height: 50,width: 50,
     child: Image.network(url))
```